# Function in function with the same variables gives me incorrect output

Tags: c, list, function, file, wchar

I have to write a program that is using polish characters. The problem is with function in a function, both have the same one of variables(like `a(int smth) b(int smth)`, this `smth` is the same one that had been used in both)

I have `open_dyk` function in main. There's text in the file, something with pl characters like `grzegżółka` in the first line, but it doesn't matter how many times I launch the program, it gives me huge A and random doubled character like yy 22, etc.

```
struct dyk{
    wchar_t line[200];
    struct dyk *next;
};
    typedef struct dyk dyk;

    dyk* add_to_bottom(wchar_t *buf, dyk *head)
    {
        dyk *current_node = head;
        dyk *new_node;

        while(current_node != NULL && current_node->next != NULL){
            current_node = current_node->next;
        }

        new_node = (dyk*)malloc(sizeof(dyk));
        wcscpy(buf, new_node->line);
        new_node->next = NULL;

        if (current_node != NULL) {
            current_node->next = new_node;
        } else {
            head = new_node;
        }

        return head;
    }

    void print_all(dyk *head) 
    {
        dyk *current_node = head;

        while ( current_node != NULL) {
            wprintf(L"%s ", current_node->line);
            current_node = current_node->next;
        }
    }

    void open_dyk(char name[100], dyk *head) 
    {
        wchar_t buforek[100];
        FILE *dyktando;
        dyktando = fopen(name, "r+");

        if(dyktando == NULL){
            wprintf(L"Błąd otwarcia pliku!\n");
        }else{
            while(!EOF){
                add_to_bottom(buforek, head);
            }
            print_all(head);
        }
        fclose(dyktando);
    }
```

main function consist:

```
system("chcp 852");
setlocale(LC_ALL, ".852");

dyk *show;
show = (dyk*)malloc(sizeof(dyk));
open_dyk("farm.txt", show);
```

As I said a bit earlier, expected result should looks like this:

```
grzegżółka?
ź ż
```

Actual results look like this:

```
A11
```

(or other variations like AYY, Abb, etc.)

Comment: Please turn that into an indented [mcve].

Comment: Whilst you're updating the indentation in your question you should probably double check you've pasted the code correctly as `while(!EOF)` doesn't look complete and there is no sign of any code that populates `buforek`

Comment: [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org) is your friend.

Comment: Another symptom of carelessly copied code: asymmetric `{}`. Fixing the indentation will help you fix that. But really, do not copy from your code, make a dedicated MCVE for StackOverflow. People here are really fond of that and it also tends to solve problems so that asking isn't needed anymore.

Comment: The code you've presented doesn't do anything with the return value of `add_to_bottom()`.  I can't be sure without an MCVE, but I'm inclined to suspect that that's a problem.

Comment: @ChrisTurner Why `while(!EOF)` look like not complete, `buforek` have been used in `add_to_bottom()`

@Yunnosch it's corrected, sry for that asymmetry at start

Comment: Hmm, unless a big typo, your code never reads anything in `open_dyk`. That is enough to later display uninitialized characters .

Comment: Because typically you'd have something like `while((c=fgetc(dyktando))!=EOF)` if you're using `EOF`. And `add_to_bottom` isn't using `buforek` - it's copying the string from the newly created node, which hasn't been initialised, so will contain garbage - call should be `wcscpy(new_node->line, buf)`...but first you need to read some text into `buforek`